# Brightscript: how to pull my Youtube videos from my own channel onto the Roku?

Tags: youtube, weather, roku, brightscript

I'm making a youtube channel for some meteorologists who hired me for an internship. 
 They want to use Youtube to pull their videos and display them onto the Roku Channel. How would I do this? also, I need to make a list of the videos from the youtube channel. one more thing if anyone knows how to pull information from a website that would be wonderful.

We have to figure out how to pull information for weather services and we have a few websites that use XML and RSS data tables, but theres so many different Weather stations that it would be a frustration to write so many If statements to contain those stations. is there a way to find their local weather station? If only one of these questions can be answered, I would prefer it be how to pull videos from youtube and play them on your channel.

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to pull YouTube videos for playback on Roku, it is disallowed by the [YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms).  If you want to stream videos, you'll need to host them on your own CDN.

Per the YouTube TOS, Section 4.C.:

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

As for weather services, you'll need to provide more information on what you're trying to do.  Most weather services (e.g., Weather Channel, Weather Underground, AccuWeather, etc.) have APIs that can identify the user's location based on IP address, but these services typically cost money, especially if you intend to use them in a commercial application.